# C - Use sigsuspend in a thread doesn't work

Tags: c, pthreads, signals

for a homework assignment I have to use only `linux` system calls to manage signals in a game, programmed in `C`.
One thing I have to do, it's to call indefinitly sigsuspend in a `thread` and wait for a `SIGALRM`,then if there is a sigalarm (signal alarm) I have to `printf()` something (doesn't matter what).

However, I tried several things but it doesn't work, I don't know how to `"deblock"` sigsuspend and print what  i want. And there is a timer in the game which send sigalrm. My code works but not the part with the `sigsuspend`
Of course I have also a `sigarlm` handler which does some stuff with `SDL` when it receives a `sigarlm`.
I don't really how I have to use masks with `sigsuspend`

**Code :**

```
//initialising sigaction struct
int init (void)

{
  // Signal handler
  sigact.sa_handler = sigalrm_handler;
  sigact.sa_flags = 0;
  sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);


  // Linked list
  head = NULL;

  sigaction(SIGALRM, &sigact, NULL);
  pthread_create(&tid_sigrecv, NULL, (void *)deamon, NULL);
  return 1; // Implementation ready ?
}
```

The sigsuspend part

```
void deamon(void * arg)
{
  int sig;
  while(1) {
    sigset_t mask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);
    sigsuspend(&mask);
    printf("in thread\n");
  }
}
```

Currently it only does not print "in thread" when a `sigarlm` is received, what should I do to use `sigsuspend` properly ? **I am obliged to use `sigsuspend`**

Answer (score 1):

You create a thread that should wait for the signal `SIGALRM` thanks to `sigsuspend()`, but instead you open the thread to all signals *but* `SIGALRM`.

Replace

```
sigemptyset(&mask);         // clear mask
sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);  // set mask to SIGALRM
sigsuspend(&mask);          // wait for any signal but blocks SIGALRM
```

with

```
sigfillset(&mask);          // mask set to all signals
sigdelset(&mask, SIGALRM);  // remove SIGALRM from the mask
sigsuspend(&mask);          // block all signals but SIGALRM
```

this way `sigsuspend()` waits for a *non* blocked signal (SIGALRM).

For testing, you could send the thread the `SIGALRM` signal using

```
pthread_kill(tid_sigrecv, SIGALRM);
```

from the *main* thread, for instance.

Comment: Ok thank you, and how can I know if a signal is blocked or not ? I can only block it with a sigprocmask() ?

Comment: `sigsuspend` blocks the said signals until the handler for a signal it doesn't block is executed. After that handler execution, signals blocking status is back to what it was before calling `sigsuspend`.